# Why is the PrintWriter still null after I call the constructor?

Tags: java, printwriter

I'm trying to write to a file, a simple note to someone who has a book in a library system.

```
try {
    PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(
        "/Users/Test/Desktop/Java/Notifacation.txt");
} catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
    System.out.println(fnfe);
}
System.out.println("Book currently loaned out and unavailable to other "
    + "members. Returning to the main menu.");
outFile.println("==========================================================="
    + "=======================================================");
outFile.println("Notifacation for " + b.whoIsCurrentLoaner());
outFile.println("We have received a request for the book currently in your posession; " + b.getTitle());
outFile.println("It would be greatly appreciated if you could return that book as soon as possible when you have finished with it");
outFile.println("==========================================================="
    + "=======================================================");
welcome();
outFile.close();
```

However it's throwing a `NullPointerException` and as I step through the code with my debugger it says that the `PrintWriter` is `null`.

How can the `PrintWriter` be `null`? I did not get an `Exception` creating the `PrintWriter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've [shadowed the variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing); from the linked Wikipedia article *variable shadowing occurs when a variable declared within a certain scope (decision block, method, or inner class) has the same name as a variable declared in an outer scope.* Comment out the type in the `try` block.

```
/* PrintWriter */ 
outFile = new PrintWriter("/Users/Test/Desktop/Java/Notifacation.txt");
```

**Edit**

Another way to create your file path is to use the [`System.getProperty(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29) to get the `"user.home"` like

```
 outFile = new PrintWriter(System.getProperty("user.home") 
     + "/Desktop/Java/Notifacation.txt");
```

That way you'll get the currently logged in user's home folder on Windows, Mac and/or Linux.

Comment: @Finlay You also have the `catch` in the wrong place. Code that depends on the success of a `try` block should be inside that `try` block.

Comment: thanks. Sorry about this. First time using PrintWriter.

Comment: @EJP sounds like your comment is the actual answer. Also IIRC PrintWriter takes a File as output stream, you probably need another variable for fh = new File("../note.txt"); before new PrintWriter(fh)

Comment: That's fixed the error but when I open the file that it creates it is empty, it hasn't been written

Comment: @softwarenewbie7331 OP can add a `null` test, I personally would prefer a [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and the Javadoc for [PrintWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter%28java.lang.String%29) says that constructor is good.

Comment: @Finlay You have to `close()` the `PrintWriter`. See the `try-with-resources` link in my last comment.

Comment: @softwarenewbie7331 No, Elliot's answer is the the answer.

Comment: Apologies @Elliot Frisch. I clicked to accept but hadn't waited long enough then completely forgot about it.

Answer (score 0):

If it throws  `null` within the  `try` block, it means the file `notifacation.txt` doesn't exist.

And surely, it will throw an exception outside the  `try` coz you have declared(or probably re-declared) and defined the `outFile` variable inside the`try` block which goes OUT OF SCOPE outside the try block.

In other words, the defination of  `outFile` from within the  `try` block  has gone out of scope and cannot be accessed by any way out of the try block.

Do this instead:

```
 PrintWriter outFile = null;
 try {

     outFile = new PrintWriter(filename);
} catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe) {

    // handle exception
}

if(outFile != null)
    outFile.close();// don't forget to close this. Else your data will not be written in the file. But this throws IOException. So handle it too.
```

Comment: Do you mean if it throws `NullPointerException`?